# FullCalendar styling issue with Wordpress admin page

Tags: fullcalendar, wordpress

I am trying to add `FullCalendar UI` on admin page in Wordpress!. However, although it loads, its style is not enabled. For instance, header option such as prev, next today are all not visible at all.

What would be the cause of the problem here?

Any help would be appreciated

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to enqueue the scripts and styles properly. The first scripts are registered and then enqueued as dependencies of `start-js` and this is the custom JS that fires the calendar. Don't enqueue external jQuery, use the one bundled with WP.

```
add_action('admin_menu', function() 
{
    $hook = add_menu_page( 
        'FC', 
        'FC', 
        'add_users', 
        'fc_admin',
        'render_page', 
        'https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2ons.png'
    );

    add_action( "admin_print_scripts-$hook", function()
    {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'ui-css', plugins_url( '/lib/cupertino/jquery-ui.min.css', __FILE__ ) );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'full-css', plugins_url( '/fullcalendar.css', __FILE__ ) );
        wp_register_script( 'moment-js', plugins_url( '/lib/moment.min.js', __FILE__ ) );
        wp_register_script( 'full-js', plugins_url( '/fullcalendar.min.js', __FILE__ ) );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'start-js', plugins_url( '/start.js', __FILE__ ), array( 'jquery', 'moment-js', 'full-js' ) );
    });
});

function render_page()
{
    ?>
    <h2>Full Calendar</h2>
    <div id='calendar'></div>
    <?php
}
```

And the `start.js` file:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({ /* SETTINGS */ });
});
```